# How long is Unicoins section available?

Tags: discussion, unicoins

Is Unicoins section like Winter Bash? If Yes, How long it will be shown in SO ? or it is available in April 1 only ?

Comment: it will be available _forever_, obviously...

Comment: It's just an Aprils fools day joke...

Comment: @Mr.Alien ok. Thanks for your information :)

Comment: April fool joke.

Comment: No, it'll be available for about **six to eight weeks**.

Answer (score 7):

Unicoins are a permanent addition to Stack Overflow.

However, if you earn at least 10 unicoins today, then you are entered in a raffle to win a [unicorn](http://promomart.espwebsite.com/ProductDetails/?productId=7006450&tab=Tile&referrerPage=ProductResults&refPgId=504580171&referrerModule=PRDREB), on us.